# What's the difference between the mass equilibrium equation and the diffusion equation?

Tags: mass, conservation-laws, differential-equations, diffusion

Was wondering whether the mass equilibrium ODE and the diffusion equation PDE stem from the same physical concepts (at least when the mass represents Chemical Pollution):

In my own words, the "trivial" mass equation states that the change of substance over time can be written as the spatial difference

$$\frac{d\rho}{dt}V = {m}(t)_{in} - {m}(t)_{out}$$

To me, the right-hand side resembles the discretization of the derivative $\frac{dm}{dx}$ (up to a small stepsize $\Delta x = 1$), and perhaps even represents some form of the differential continuity equation, with no generation factor $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot \vec J=0$.

The diffusion equation, on the other hand, states that the change in substance over time is in fact proportional to the second-order spatial derivative

$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = D\nabla^2\rho$$

which is nothing but plugging the assumption of $\vec J\propto \nabla \rho$ into the continuity equation.

If so, what is the difference between the two - aren't both of these describe the same thing? what causes the right-hand side to look different? Is one equation more accurate than the other?

Thanks!

Comment: The right side of your first equation should have $\dot\rho$ instead of $\rho$, yes? Right now the units don't even match. For clarity and readability and to avoid confusion in answers, please review to make sure your equations are appearing as intended.

Comment: [Derivation of Fick's second law from mass conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Derivation_of_Fick's_second_law).